# ¿Como añadir espacio en blanco entre strings formateadas?

Tags: python-3.x, string

necesito ayuda con este pequeño reto, el objetivo es crear una función que reciba una lista de operaciones aritméticas y además un booleano opcional que indica que se va a mostrar el resultado de la operación o no y devuelva la operación formateada de la siguiente manera:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```

Logré generar cada una de las operaciones con el formato correcto, el problema es que no sé cómo hacer que estén separadas verticalmente una de las otras por un espacio de 4 espacios vacíos en cada una de las líneas; actualmente las separo por una nueva línea con `\n`.
Esta es la manera en como creé la función:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, showResult=False):

    formatted_operations = ""

    if(len(problems) > 5):
        return "Error: Too many problems"

    for problem in problems:
        splited_problem = problem.split()
        first_number, second_number = splited_problem[0], splited_problem[2]
        operator = splited_problem[1]

        try:
            int(first_number)
            int(second_number)
        except:
            return "Error: Numbers must only contain digits"

        if operator != "+" and operator != "-":
            return(f"Error: Operator must be '+' or '-', got: {operator}")

        operator = operator[0]

        if len(first_number) > 4 or len(second_number) > 4:
            return "Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits"

        separator_number = max([len(first_number), len(second_number)]) + 2
        third_line = ("-" * separator_number)
        first_line = f"{' '* (separator_number - len(first_number))}{first_number}"
        second_line = f"{operator}{' ' * (((separator_number - len(second_number)))-1)}{second_number}"

        operation_to_add = f"{first_line}\n{second_line}\n{third_line}\n"

        if not showResult:
            formatted_operations += operation_to_add
        if showResult:
            result = 0
            if operator == "+":
                result = int(first_number) + int(second_number)
            else:
                result = int(first_number) - int(second_number)

            fourth_line = f"{' ' * (((separator_number - len(second_number)))-1)}{result}"
            operation_to_add += f"{fourth_line}\n"
            formatted_operations += operation_to_add

    return formatted_operations
```

Si a la funcion le paso por ejemplo:

```
print(arithmetic_arranger(["32 + 8", "1 - 3801", "9999 + 9999", "523 - 49"], True))
```

Me imprime las operaciones una debajo de otra, las necesito separadas verticalmente por 4 espacios vacíos, como en el ejemplo ¿cómo lo tendría que hacer?

Comment: Una idea que se me ocurre es que trabajes con cada linea por separado (por ejemplo, armar una lista con cada linea e ir concatenando cada "parte" de cada problema a la linea correspondiente). Luego unes todas las lineas resultantes con \n

Answer (score 1):

El "gran problema" que tienes es que estás ignorando uno de los principales pilares de la [programación estructurada](https://www.google.com/search?q=programaci%C3%B3n+estructurada): la delegación de funcionalidad. Y estás trantado de resolver todo en un solo bloque de código.

Aunque no creas, no está tan fácil formatear esas cadenas, porque tienes que calcular la longitud de la más larga, independientemente en cuál linea se encuentra y luego imprimir las demás en base a esa referencia.
De salida, ya eso te está diciendo algo: **NO** puedes calcular e imprimir en la misma rutina, porque tienes que hacer otras evaluaciones previas.

Mi propuesta es la siguiente, crear una cadena en blanco con la longitud total y luego reemplazar el final de la misma con el elemento actual, algo asi. Estoy usando asteriscos (`*`) en vez de espacios para que se vea:

```py
>>> sep = 4 # separador
>>> elem = '53' # Uno de los números
>>> signo = '+'
>>> max_len = 4 # numero más largo de la operacion
>>> spc_sep = '*' * sep # El separador (*) para que se vea
>>> spc_elem = '*' * (max_len + 2)
>>> all_spc = spc_sep + spc_elem
>>> print(all_spc)
**********
>>> # Ahora reemplazar el elemento en la ultima parte de all_spc
>>> len_elem = len(elem)
>>> print(all_spc[:-len_elem] + elem)
********53 # <-- Esto es lo que necesitas
>>> # Y con el signo:
>>> all_spc = spc_sep + signo + spc_elem[1:]
>>> print(all_spc)
****+*****
>>> print(all_spc[:-len_elem] + elem)
****+***53
```

Lo anterior es el concepto que necesitas. Ahora tienes de tarea obtener las siguientes 3 listas:

```
# La lista de las 3 líneas de la operación
lines = [
    ['32', '1', '9999', '523'],
    ['8', '3801', '9999', '49'], 
    ['40', '-3800', '19998', '474']
]

# La lista con los signos de cada operación
sign = ['+', '-', '+', '-']

# La lista de la longitud máxima de los elementos en cada operación.
# En este caso no se toma en cuenta la última linea, de resultado.
# Pero si fuese multiplicación, se debe considerar.
max_len = [2, 4, 4, 3]
```

Una vez obtienes lo anterior, entonces puedes crear una función aplicando los conceptos ya expuestos:

```py
middle_lines = ['-'*(x + 2) for x in max_len]
spc_sep = ' ' * sep

for i in range(len(lines)):
    line = lines[i]
    if i == 2:
        print(spc_sep.join(middle_lines))
    for j in range(len(line)):
        elem = line[j]
        len_elem = len(elem)
        spc_elem = ' ' * (max_len[j] + 2)
        separator = '' if j == 0 else spc_sep
        if i == 1:
            all_spc = separator + sign[j] + spc_elem[1:]
        else:
            all_spc = separator + spc_elem[:]
        to_print = all_spc[:-len_elem] + elem
        print(to_print, end='')
    print()
```

`separator` es vacío cuando `j == 0` para que quede pegado al margen izquierdo. Y esto imprime:

```
  32         1      9999      523
+  8    - 3801    + 9999    -  49
----    ------    ------    -----
  40     -3800     19998      474
```